# wordpress qtranslate flags dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, qtranslate

I'm using "qtranslate" plugin for word press to use metalanguage in my site,

How can i create a combo that will display only the flags in it ?

i have tried using the following code to generate the dropdown but it only displays the flags in a list:

```
echo qtrans_generateLanguageSelectCode('image');
$header_shortcodes = html_entity_decode(get_option(PREFIX.'_header_shortcodes'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo $header_shortcodes = apply_filters('themefuse_shortcodes',$header_shortcodes);
```

Thanks

Comment: have u been able to find a solution for this?

Comment: well , i had to solve it myself eventually , i took one of the advices here and wrote it myself. i edited the plugin and used msDropdown plugin to create the image list. i will post the code in a sec

Comment: thanks man! I recommend you to set your own answer as the answer for this, so other people can find some help :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually took one of the solutions here and combined it with [msdropdown](http://www.lookmywebpage.com/technology/jquery/jquery-image-combobox-using-msdropdown/) plugin

Step 1: Go to the plugin folder and open qtranslate/qtranslate_widget.php. There in line no. 112 you will find case:'both'; Now where that case ends its line no 123 Below that add the following code (another case written)

```
case 'bothkria': ?>
     <div id="language_chooser">
        <select name="langchooser" id="langchooser" onchange="$(window.location).attr('href',this.value);">
        <?php 
            /************************
            * go over the enabled languages and create all the languages options
            * the first marked "selected" is reffered to the current chosen language
            * the value is the relevant url and the title is the url of the image.
            * 
            * After creating the selectbox we will run the msdropdown plugin to make it a designed select box
            * Of corse dont forget to have a reference to the msdropdown js library
            * <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dd.js"></script>
            * you can find it here http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown
            *************************/
            foreach(qtrans_getSortedLanguages() as $language)
            {
                if($q_config['language']==$language) {?>
                    <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo qtrans_convertURL($url, $language);?>" title="<?php echo get_option('home');?>/wp-content/<?php echo $q_config['flag_location'];?><?php echo $q_config['flag'][$language] ?>"><?php print strtoupper($q_config['pre_domain'][$language]); ?></option>
          <?php } else {  ?>
                    <option value="<?php print qtrans_convertURL($url, $language);?>" title="<?php echo get_option('home');?>/wp-content/<?php echo $q_config['flag_location'];?><?php echo $q_config['flag'][$language] ?>"><?php print strtoupper($q_config['pre_domain'][$language]); ?></option>
          <?php }
            } ?>
        </select> 
        <div id="selectbox_script" style="display:none;">
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                 /* <![CDATA[ */
                    $(document).ready(function(e) {
                        try {
                        $("#langchooser").msDropDown();
                        } catch(e) {
                        alert(e.message);
                        }
                    });
                 /* ]]> */
                 </script>
        </div>
     </div>
    <?php break; ?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use msdropdown here?

Comment: well you have the exact details in the reply above ... it was a long time ago , since then im not working with this plugin anymore - i have switched to WPML which I think is much better and comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is that you need a dropdown list with both flag image and language if it is so then use the below code.

This code i have written and tested on qtranslate version 2.5.28 although it will work for other version as well reference line numbers are given according to this version.

Step 1: Go to the plugin folder and open qtranslate/qtranslate_widget.php. There in line no. 112 you will find `case:'both';`
Now where that case ends its line no 123
Below that add the following code (another case written)
`

```
case 'bothkria':
            if($_REQUEST['lang']!=""){ $kria = $_REQUEST['lang'];}else{$kria = $q_config['default_language'];}
            echo '<span class="s_selected"><img src="'.get_option('home').'/wp-content/'.$q_config['flag_location'].''.$q_config['flag'][$kria].'" alt="'.$q_config['flag'][$kria].'" /> '.$q_config['language_name'][$kria].'</span>
                    <ul class="s_options">';
            foreach(qtrans_getSortedLanguages() as $language){
                      echo '<li><a href="'.qtrans_convertURL($url, $language).'"><img src="'.get_option('home').'/wp-content/'.$q_config['flag_location'].''.$q_config['flag'][$language].'" alt="'.$q_config['language_name'][$language].'" />'.$q_config['language_name'][$language].'</a></li>';
            }
                    echo '</ul>';
            break;
```

Step 2: Where you want to display it just paste the below code
`<div id="language_switcher" class="s_switcher"><?php echo qtrans_generateLanguageSelectCode('bothkria'); ?></div>`

Step 3: CSS Classes it was accordingly designed given here for your help you can change according to your theme.
`

```
.s_switcher {
              z-index: 10;
              position: absolute;
              top:6px;
              right:255px;
              font-size: 11px;
              background: #f6f6f6 url(../images/dropdown.gif) no-repeat 100% 6px;
              border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
              border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
              border-right: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
              border-radius: 3px;
              -moz-border-radius: 3px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            }
            .s_switcher ul {
              margin-bottom: 0;
            }
            .s_switcher span.s_selected,
            .s_switcher li,
            .s_switcher li a
            {
              display: block;
              height: 22px;
              line-height: 20px;
              text-indent: 7px;
            }
            .s_switcher span.s_selected {
              cursor: default;
              color: #999;
            }
            .s_switcher .s_options {
              cursor: pointer;
              display: none;
            }
            .s_switcher img {
              display: inline;
              margin: -1px 3px 0 0;
              vertical-align: middle;
              margin-left:10px;
            }

            #language_switcher .s_selected, #language_switcher .s_options li a {
                font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-size:12px;
                color:#333;
                }

            #language_switcher .s_options li a{
                color:#999;}
            #language_switcher .s_options li a:hover{
                color:#333;}
```

`
Done upload the files and check.
Hope this is what you wanted.
Enjoy

Thank you!

Comment: thanks

i tried this but it does not appear as a dropdown, it just generated a <ul> , how can i make it appear as a drop ?